# restarting was server everytime I make changes to java files

Tags: websphere, rad

I am using WAS 7.0 and my IDE is RAD.I had to restart my server every time I make changes in any java file. Without restarting server my changes are not getting deployed.Do I need to change any settings to resolve this?

Comment: How are your Java classes packaged and deployed?

Comment: Have you tried republishing instead of restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your server configuration in RAD.
 Double click on you server and check all options. 
 You should find something that named automatic publish.

Where is another option for redeployment, it's named [WebSphere Rapid Deployment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21391318).

Comment: I checked it and changed the settings still no use.Anything else to try?

Comment: The exact problem is : When I publish after making nay changes in Java files, its not reflecting. If I restart the server only those changes are getting reflected. This is making me to restart my server even for a very minor change in Java file.

Comment: Server is not in development mode by default. You should check this option on the application server tab and restart it.

Comment: Issue with my application code. Resolved it..Thanks for your valuable time Anton

Comment: how to tick start the server in dev mode?